# Migration failed after upgrading to dotnet core 3.1

Tags: c#, autofac, npgsql, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

After upgrading my `dotnet core 2.1` app to `dotnet core 3.1` I cannot create new migrations. This is my configurations:

My Startup looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddOptions();

    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
    });
    // other configurations
}

public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder) {
    // register my services in autofac
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env){
    // configure stuff 
}
```

And Program:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
       .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
```

And here is my `DbContext`:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext  {

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options):base(options) {}
}
```

Now, when I run this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
```

I get this error:

> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration.
>   See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator =
>   DbContextOptions[] (DelegateActivator), Services =
>   [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions,
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]], Lifetime =
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership
>   = ExternallyOwned ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details.
>   Registration: Activator = DbContextOptions (DelegateActivator),
>   Services = [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions], Lifetime
>   = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the
>   activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for
>   details. Registration: Activator = DbContextOptions`1
>   (DelegateActivator), Services =
>   [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[Manex.Micro.Auth.Data.DataContext,
>   Manex.Micro.Auth, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]], Lifetime =
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared,
>   Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> Method 'get_Info' in type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.NpgsqlOptionsExtension'
>   from assembly 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' does not have an
>   implementation. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner
>   exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)

I google the part *Method 'get_Info' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.NpgsqlOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL* a lot, but nothing comes out. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Here is my library stack: `C#`, `ASP.NET Core 3.1`, `.NET Core 3.1`, `NPGSQL`, `Autofac`.

**UPDATE:**

I removed `Autofac` and changed my `DbContext` to a simple context with one simple entity. Now, the only error I'm getting is this:

> Method 'get_Info' in type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.NpgsqlOptionsExtension'
>   from assembly 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' does not have an
>   implementation.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#config) can be of any help.

Comment: @ArthurGrigoryan Thanks for the link. It didnt help.

Comment: You seem to be mixing versions of EFCore / Npgsql - version 1.1.0.0 definitely shouldn't be in there. Check your csproj carefully and post it here if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @ShayRojansky It wasnt version conflict. It was a mistake in framework condition in `csproj`. Actually I have 2 reference groups for both `2.1` and `3.1`, and in `3.1` section, my condition was `3.0`. Ill post the answer.